# Xpath query help Google ImportXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Im having a bit of an issue with the Xpath Query to grab the URL link from a table dependant on the text in another cell on the table row

https://zkillboard.com/character/1643058377/losses/

For example in the URL I want to grab the URL from the "View" Anchor but for particular ship types. For example in that URL the Victim CEll would have to contain (Sabre)

any ideas

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XPath expression like below:

```
//a[normalize-space(.)='View'][../preceding-sibling::td[contains(.,' (Sabre)')]]/@href
```

Comment: This does not seem to work it bring the text "VIEW" back only I need the URL link not the anchor text

Comment: Then you need to add the @href attribute at the end. Updated the answer.

Comment: Like that //a[normalize-space(.)='View'][../preceding-sibling::td[contains(.,' (Daredevil)')]]/@href

Comment: Does query allow multiple HTML to be imported???? its only the continue function does not seem to be working anymore. please review here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvsJEW3z7v3edGVtYVczM2JMT2tkSDhhaGdQaFl1MlE&usp=drive_web#gid=2

Comment: The issue shows only when you try to prefix the @href with the site name: `="https://zkillboard.com/" & ImportXML($B$10,$C$18)`. Without that prefix all values are correctly shown in the column. I could not overcome this issue. I suggest starting a separate topic on this.